# How could i export gridview data to ms word

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview

I am working on asp.net 4.0 web application development using c#. I am trying to export the Gridview data to ms word document. I have used the following code.

```
Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=MyWord.doc");
        Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF7;
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.word";
        System.IO.StringWriter oStringWriter = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter oHtmlTextWriter = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(oStringWriter);
        this.GridView1.RenderControl(oHtmlTextWriter);
        Response.Output.Write(oStringWriter.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
```

The application is running without problems but it returns the data in word like

```
   +ADw-div+AD4- +ADw-table cellspacing+AD0AIg-0+ACI- cellpadding+AD0AIg-4+ACI- id+AD0AIg-GridView1+ACI- style+AD0AIg-color:+ACM-333333+ADs-border-collapse:collapse+ADsAIgA+- +ADw-tr style+AD0AIg-color:White+ADs-background-color:+ACM-507CD1+ADs-font-weight:bold+ADsAIgA+- +ADw-th scope+AD0AIg-col+ACIAPg-FileId+ADw-/th+AD4APA-th scope+AD0AIg-col+ACIAPg-PortalId+ADw-/th+AD4APA-th scope+AD0AIg-col+ACIAPg-FileName+ADw-/th+AD4APA-th scope+AD0AIg-col+ACIAPg-Extension+ADw-/th+AD4APA-th scope+AD0AIg-col+ACIAPg-Size+ADw-/th+AD4APA-th scope+AD0AIg-col+ACIAPg-Width+ADw-
```

I know it is much similar to html but how could i convert this into actual one. guide me.

Comment: I don't know what similarity you saw between HTML and the snippet you posted but I were you aware that the `.doc` MS Word format is a proprietary binary file format? Have yo ever opened a `.doc` file generated by MS Word in Notepad yo see what it resembles? You seem to be writing some text file which obviously has nothing to do with the actual format.

Comment: here i find div,style,cellpadding,tableand td,th in the document. How could we convert that binary format to actual table structure

Comment: You have to use a third party library. .NET has nothing built-in that allows you to generate Word files.

Comment: Recent versions of MS Word use an open standard which is essentially an xml document.  Ensure that you conform to this standard and slap a .docx extension on it.  [Start here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordProcessingML#ISO.2FIEC_29500:2008) to learn a little bit about it.

Answer (score 0):

this is works for me it requires [itextsharp.dll](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/files/latest/download)

```
            string FName = "filename.doc";
            mygrid.AllowPaging = false;
            mygrid.DataSource = datasource();
            mygrid.DataBind();
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", FName));
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.ContentType = "application/ms-word";
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            mygrid.RenderControl(htw);
            Response.Write(sw.ToString());
            Response.End();
```